# STUArray type parameter in an in-place polymorphic quicksort

Tags: haskell

I want to implement a polymorphic quicksort. I would like to specify that
type a in  `IArray UArray a => [a] -> [a]` and `ST s (STUArray s Int a)` are the same type. How can I do that ?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Quicksort where

import Control.Monad.ST (ST)
import Data.Array.ST (runSTUArray, newListArray, STUArray)
import Data.Array.IArray (elems)
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray, IArray)

quicksort :: IArray UArray a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort l = elems $ runSTUArray $
  do newListArray (0, 9) l :: ST s (STUArray s Int a)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make it through to the next error by enabling `ScopedTypeVariables` and [supplying an explicit `forall`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XScopedTypeVariables) in the top level type signature:

```
quicksort :: forall a. IArray UArray a => [a] -> [a]
```

You will then discover that your `STUArray` is not an instance of `MArray`, because there is [no instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html#t:STUArray) for arbitrary `a`. If you make it an `Int`, it will compile.

And the reason for the conspicuous absence of such an instance is, of course, that an *unboxed* array can only contain an *unboxeable* value, which would be a value of a *primitive* type, an exhaustive roster of which you may review in [the relevant documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.5.1.1/GHC-Prim.html).

Comment: Surely this could be ameliorated with an extra constraint. Import `Data.Constraint Forall`, define `type UnboxF a s = MArray (STUArray s) a (ST s)`, `class UnboxF a s => UnboxC a s`, `instance UnboxF a s => UnboxC a s`, add a constraint `Forall (UnboxC a)` to the function and use `inst` as needed.

Comment: @dfeuer I find this comment very hard to understand. Specifically, what is this `inst` you refer to?

Comment: See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Data.Constraint.Forall` to make this work for anything unboxable. It may not be the most efficient, though, because of the way that mechanism works. A more annoying but probably better way would be to write an `MArray`-like class taking a constructor that expects an `s` argument.

```
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses, ScopedTypeVariables, ConstraintKinds,
  FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances, TypeOperators #-}
module QS where

import Control.Monad.ST (ST, runST)
import Data.Constraint (Dict (..), (:-) (..))
import Data.Constraint.Forall (Forall, inst)
import Data.Array.ST (runSTUArray, newListArray, STUArray, MArray)
import Data.Array.IArray (elems)
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray, IArray)

type UnboxF a s = MArray (STUArray s) a (ST s)

class UnboxF a s => UnboxC a s
instance UnboxF a s => UnboxC a s

marrayDict :: Forall (UnboxC a) => Dict (UnboxC a s)
marrayDict = case inst :: Forall (UnboxC a) :- UnboxC a s of
               Sub x -> x

quicksort :: forall a. (IArray UArray a, Forall (UnboxC a)) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort l = elems $ runSTUArray
  ( case marrayDict :: Dict (UnboxC a s) of { Dict ->
      do
        newListArray (0,9) l
    } :: forall s. ST s (STUArray s Int a))

test :: [Char] -> [Char]
test = quicksort
```